# reading formula from excel into pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an Excel sheet, wherein I have formulas written like normal expression format in an excel sheet(for example:Sheet1) as shown below.

```
KPI FORMULAE

A2  A+B

B2  B+C
```

In the same excel sheet, I have the data like this(for example:Sheet2):

```
A   B   C

1   2   6

2   4   6

3   6   6

4   8   6

5   4   6
```

I want to read the formula from Sheet1 and get 2 new columns in Sheet2 in a pandas Dataframe so that my result will look like

```
A   B   C   A2  B2

1   2   6   3   8

2   4   6   6   10

3   6   6   9   12

4   8   6   12  14

5   4   6   9   10
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

when I try to read the excel in python, I just get normal text A+B, but how to get `df['A']+df['B']`?
Is there any way in particular please suggest me.

Comment: do you have complicated formulae where more than 2 columns and more advance operations involved?

Comment: yes some formulae have all add, sub, multiplication & division( limited to only these four operations). & more than 2 columns involved

Comment: only 4 operations are involved.. add, sub, mult & division(for example: 100*((A+B)/(B+C))

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using `eval()`

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'KPI':['A2', 'B2'], 'FORMULAE':['A_A+A_B','100*((A_A+A_B)/(A_B+A_C))']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A_A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'A_B':[7,2,5,6,7], 'A_C':[1,9,6,3,2]})

cols = df2.columns

def func(x):
  op = x
  for c in cols:
    if c in x:
      op = op.replace(c,"df2['{}']".format(c))
  return op

df1['FORMULAE'] = df1['FORMULAE'].apply(func)

for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
  df2[row['KPI']] = eval(row['FORMULAE'])
```

Output:

```
    A_A A_B A_C A2  B2
0   1   7   1   8   100.000000
1   2   2   9   4   36.363636
2   3   5   6   8   72.727273
3   4   6   3   10  111.111111
4   5   7   2   12  133.333333
```

In your case use `pandas.read_excel()` to read the data from excel file.

Comment: thanks Akshay for providing a solution. I will give it a try

Comment: If I have "underscore" in the column names like "_A","_B", then how can I use isaplha?(only underscore character exists)

Comment: Do you also have underscore in formula if you have underscore in column name?

Comment: yes.. same column name is represented in the formula(only underscore character exists).for example, I have column names like : pmsinrpucchdistr_vec8. Hence I have total formula like :        
          """100 *(pmsinrpucchdistr_vec7) / (pmsinrpucchdistr_vec0  + pmsinrpucchdistr_vec1 + pmsinrpucchdistr_vec2 + pmsinrpucchdistr_vec3 + pmsinrpucchdistr_vec4 +pmsinrpucchdistr_vec5 +pmsinrpucchdistr_vec6 + pmsinrpucchdistr_vec7 + pmsinrpucchdistr_vec8) """

Comment: In some cases, I have like this """((pmMacHarqDlNack16qam - pmMacHarqDlDtx16qam) / pmMacHarqDlAck16qam)"""

Comment: @amrutha Check the new answer

Comment: Thanks for the new solution Akshay. I will try the new code.

Comment: I am facing substring issue here.. for example, if I have expression like "f=func('pmprbavaildl+pmprbavaildlmbms')", then I get output as ""df2['pmprbavaildl']+df2['df2['pmprbavaildl']mbms']", provided, both "pmprbavaildlmbms" and "pmprbavaildl" are present in cols list.